# Running Python scripts on an Ubuntu machine disables the network port

Tags: networking, python

One of the Ubuntu machines I manage is having an issue where it completely disables the network port every time I run a Python script on it. It does not matter what the script is, after about 5 minutes of execution, the network show as unreachable. I have tried disabling and re-enabling the network via the terminal but this does not bring the port back online. Even doing a normal reboot does nothing, I have to physically unplug the machine to get it to come back up. Has anyone had this problem before?

Edit: Linux version 4.15.0-99-generic (gcc version 7.5.0). The network is a domain with this computer hooking up via a dynamic IP linked to a static IP router. This is only one of about 50 Linux machines we (college IT staff) manage and this is the only one that has ever done anything like this. Other computers in the same room with the exact same network setup run scripts perfectly.

Comment: Welcome! Without knowing what the script actually does, I'm not sure anyone can help you. Python is just another interpreter and scripting language. Nothing special about it to normally cause your interfaces disable. Please at least provide us with your OS version, name of your hypervisor program (if it's a vm), and tell us if it is a private network or an organisation network that may be affected by other network components / programs or overall some security policy that may cause this.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]